# Difference between allThreads and grpThreads in JTL file?

Tags: java, jmeter, performance-testing

I've been developing custom dashboard from JMeter jtl file and it's hard to understand what it means for each columns.

For example, if I make a jmeter test file as...
[image]

and result jtl file looks like this..

[image]

My question is

1. As you can see from the jtl file, thread number start from 6 not 1. If thread group's state is 6, why does the counted rows of thread group '6' is 1? For all I know, each thread groups represents virtual users, so I expect if thread groups are 6 there will be 6 requests be sent.
2. What's the difference between grpThreads and all Threads? I'm going to draw response time over active thread groups(virtual users), for example, which value should I use?

Answer (score 0):

Both are numbers of **currently active users**

- `grpThreads` - for current Thread Group
- `allThreads` - for all Thread Groups (not applicable for your case because you have only one Thread Group)

the number of active threads starts from 6 due to your ramp-up  settings, according to your configuration JMeter starts 20 threads in 5 seconds

Looking into .jtl file doesn't give you the full picture I'd recommend loading the file into a [Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html), for example [Active Threads Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/) is a good choice for tracking concurrency  (it can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager))

Also you can generate [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#report_only) which provides nice [apdex tables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#overview) and charts

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I’m still confused by the value of grpThreads. Active threads number does not match with the counts of the sent requests. In .jtl file, the row of grpThreads 6 only one and grpThreads 7 counts only 2. I guess it’s because the interval of the requests are too short in the beginning of the test when threads are increasing?